# Understanding ListT IO Example

Tags: haskell

Given the following from the well-written [From Simple IO to Monad Transformers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00KN6XZ1M):

```
import Control.Monad.List

type Lio = ListT IO

test :: Lio ()
test = do
   x <- return [1,2]
   y <- ListT $ return ['a', 'b']
   lift $ putStrLn (show (x, y))
```

Please explain the final line of output, `[(), ()]`:

```
*Main> runListT test
([1,2],'a')
([1,2],'b')
[(),()]
```

Comment: That's the output of `lift`.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** If you see something you didn't expect in GHCi, think of the type of the line that yielded that result.

---

`test` has the type `ListT IO ()`. If we use `runListT` on a `ListT m a`, we end up with a `m [a]`:

```
runListT      :: Monad m => ListT  m  a  ->  m  [a]
test          ::            ListT IO ()
runListT test ::                            IO [()]
```

Since `[()]` can be shown (and is not `()`), GHCi shows you the result. You won't see it if you bind it:

```
*Main> res <- runListT test
([1,2],'a')
([1,2],'b')
*Main> res
[(),()]
```

In the end, it's somewhat related to the output of `replicateM 10 $ print 1`. It collects all the results of `print 1`, which aren't very interesting. However, it's easy to write `runListT_` to get rid of those:

```
*Main> let runListT_ m = runListT m >> return ()
*Main> runListT_ test
([1,2],'a')
([1,2],'b')
```